# PHP - eliminate the need to pass the value by reference

Tags: php, recursion

I have a **working** function which **flood-fill**s a **closed area** in a **zero matrix**, **recursively**, given X and Y inside the area.

```
function MatrixFloodFill(&$matrix, $x, $y)
{
    if($matrix[$x][$y] == 0)
    {
        $matrix[$x][$y] = 1;
        MatrixFloodFill($matrix, $x+1, $y);
        MatrixFloodFill($matrix, $x-1, $y);
        MatrixFloodFill($matrix, $x, $y+1);
        MatrixFloodFill($matrix, $x, $y-1);
    }

    return $matrix;
}
```

Because I call this function recursively more than **1** time, I cannot just return the function. I have to return in the end. Because of this I have to **pass the matrix by reference**, as you see. Otherwise it won't work.

How can I change this code so I can **pass the matrix by value** and the function will **return the new, flood-filled matrix**?

Thanks!

Comment: You actually **can** pass the matrix by value **and** return the modified matrix. Just don't forget to use this information for **all** the recursive call the function does. Another possibility is to wrap the array into an object that implements interface `ArrayAccess` but it requires more work.

Comment: How exactly? Could you please show me some code?

Comment: Whatever operation you do, you can always do the operation on the parameter and return it's new value. It doesn't matter on what type the function operates or whether it is recursive or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually can avoid using references if you change the function to get the array as a parameter, modify it and return it. All you have to do is to remember that when you call it recursively:

```
function MatrixFloodFill(array $matrix, $x, $y)
{
    if($matrix[$x][$y] == 0) {
        // Modify the matrix
        $matrix[$x][$y] = 1;
        // Pass the modified matrix to the recursive call and ...
        // ... store the value it returns (a modified copy of the matrix)
        $matrix = MatrixFloodFill($matrix, $x+1, $y);
        // ... do the same again and again ...
        $matrix = MatrixFloodFill($matrix, $x-1, $y);
        $matrix = MatrixFloodFill($matrix, $x, $y+1);
        $matrix = MatrixFloodFill($matrix, $x, $y-1);
    }

    // Return the modified matrix    
    return $matrix;
}
```

**Update**

As @Daniel comments, during the execution of the function, each time the `if` block is executed, the line `$matrix[$x][$y] = 1` produces a new copy of the matrix. Only the last such copy is retained (it is returned by the topmost call of the function and probably saved in a variable by the calling code), all the others are destroyed.

The number of copies created during the execution of the function is equal to the number of elements that are modified (at most the total number of elements in the matrix). If this number is large then the script uses a lot of processing time to create many copies and discard all of them but the last one.

The only advantage of passing the matrix by value is the code cleanness and testability (which is not a small thing, by the way). However, you can keep the testability and cleanness if you mark the original function (using references) as an implementation detail (the language doesn't help you here, you can explain this in the function's documentation), write a wrapper function that gets the matrix by value, calls the **by reference** function then returns the updated matrix and use only the wrapper function (it is the public interface).

Even better, you should embed the data and the code in a class. It should also store the matrix' dimensions (the code you posted does not check them and the recursion never stops; I assumed the posted code is a minimal example and the real code handles the matrix' dimensions correctly).

Comment: It should be pointed out that you'll be creating many copies of the matrix arrays in this case.  The "by reference" implementation is actually much better.  If you need one that doesn't do "by reference", then you should wrap the "by reference" recursive method with another method that returns the result.

Answer (score 1):

axiac posted an answer to your question which made a recursive function that doesn't take the matrix by reference.  That will work, but is far less efficient.

I would suggest keeping your original method, but then adding another wrapper:

```
function MatrixFloodFillRef(&$matrix, $x, $y)
{
    if($matrix[$x][$y] == 0)
    {
        $matrix[$x][$y] = 1;
        MatrixFloodFillRef($matrix, $x+1, $y);
        MatrixFloodFillRef($matrix, $x-1, $y);
        MatrixFloodFillRef($matrix, $x, $y+1);
        MatrixFloodFillRef($matrix, $x, $y-1);
    }

    return $matrix;
}

function MatrixFloodFill($matrix, $x, $y)
{
    MatrixFloodFillRef($matrix, $x, $y);

    return $matrix;
}
```